# docker registry - multiple auth methods

Tags: docker, authentication, docker-registry

I have the following problem: I am hosting a docker registry and I need to use it with 2 different "clients".

One of those clients is gitlab where I use token auth mechanism. On the other side I have a different client which only support basic auth, so if I configure the registry to allow basic auth I cannot use gitlab and vice versa.

Is there a best/common practice for this type of scenarios? Is it even possible to have 2 auth mechanisms for the same registry?

Thanks!